# Print networkx DiGraph to Nested JSON format

Tags: python, json, serialization, d3.js, networkx

I have a networkx DiGraph.

```
>> G = nx.DiGraph()
>> G.add_edges_from(product([0],[1,2])) # product is itertools.product 
>> G.add_edges_from(product([1],[3,4]))
```

The graph looks like this inside:

```
>> G.adj  
 {0: {1: {}, 2: {}},  
  1: {3: {}, 4: {}},  
  2: {},  
  3: {},  
  4: {}}
```

I would like this to be printed to a json format like the following:

```
{   
    name: 0,
    children: [ 
        {
            name: 1,
            children: [
                {
                    name: 3,
                    children: [] 
                }, 
                {
                    name: 4,
                    children: []
                }
                ]
        }, 
        {
            name: 2,
            children:[]
        }
    ]
}
```

(The reason being, I am trying to write it in a format that this D3 visualization takes in. https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4063550)

I am not sure how to go about this. Any help much appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: You are going to have to make this manually yourself.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Christopher's answer works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `json_graph.tree_data()` to output the data in a nested format.

From [the documentation](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.json_graph.tree_data.html#networkx.readwrite.json_graph.tree_data)

```
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
import networkx as nx
import json
G = nx.DiGraph([(1,2)])
data = json_graph.tree_data(G,root=1)
s = json.dumps(data)
```

Which gives `{"id": 1, "children": [{"id": 2}]}`

Answer (score 0):

```
`// Set up the D3.js canvas and force layout
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const width = +svg.attr("width");
const height = +svg.attr("height");
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(d => d.id))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

// Load the data for the graph (empty initially)
let nodes = [];
let links = [];

// Define the drag behavior for the nodes
const drag = d3.drag()
  .on("start", dragStart)
  .on("drag", dragging)
  .on("end", dragEnd);

function dragStart(event, d) {
  if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragging(event, d) {
  d.fx = event.x;
  d.fy = event.y;
}

function dragEnd(event, d) {
  if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

// Define the update function for the graph
function update() {
  // Create the link and node elements
  const link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .join("line")
      .attr("class", "link");
  const node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .call(drag);

  // Update the positions of the link and node elements
  link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
  node.attr("cx", d => d.x)
      .attr("cy", d => d.y);

  // Update the simulation with the new node and link data
  simulation.nodes(nodes).on("tick", ticked);
  simulation.force("link").links(links);

  function ticked() {
    link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
    node.attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  }
}

// Call the update function initially to render the empty graph
update();

// Define the event listener for adding new nodes
svg.on("click", event => {
  // Add a new node with a unique ID
  const newNode = {id: nodes.length.toString()};
  nodes.push(newNode);

  // Add a new link to any existing node
  if (nodes.length > 1) {
    const source = nodes[nodes.length - 2];
    const target = newNode;
    const newLink = {source, target};
    links.push(newLink);
  }

  // Update the graph display
  update();
});
`
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. It would improve your answer if you add some description what your code does and why it is helpful to the author. By the way, this post is 9 years old and has an accepted answer with some votes meaning it is quite useful. So perhaps use your skills and focus on actual questions. Have fun here!